# Keypress simulation not firing

Tags: jquery, keypress

Im trying to simulate ENTER keypress on page load, but it is not firing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Focus on city field on page load
    $('input#search_city').focus();

    $(function() {
        if($("input#search_city").length>0 && $("input#search_city").val() != ''){

                var e = $.Event("keypress");
                e.which = 13;
                e.keyCode = 13;
                $("input#search_city").trigger(e);

        }
    });

});
```

Value of input field is set via GET variable and on page load its code looks like this. JS file is included on the bottom of the page, above body closing tag.

```
<input type="text" id="search_city" placeholder="Select city/town" autocomplete="off" class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" value="Novi Sad, Serbia">
```

Why is this not firing?

Comment: You misspelled `keypress`, you left off the last `s`.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to use `$(function()...)` inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @Barmar if so what would happen..?

Comment: Its a typo, while I was editing code here. updated and still not firing

Comment: `$(function ...)` is the same as `$(document).ready(function...))`. So both functions will be executed when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is `keypress`. Not `keypres`:

```
var e = $.Event("keypress");
                      //^-------------- add s
```

See, that's a typo.

### After edit:

I can't reproduce your problem. Sorry.

Comment: yes I see, typo i made here, its keypress in code and still not firing

Comment: @user2764141, welcome, even though, I didn't help you out much